# Functional equation $f(n^2+1)-f(n^2)=1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, functional-equations

Let $\mathbb{N}^*$ be the set of positive integers and $\mathcal{P}$ be the set of primes.
I seek to prove that if $f:\mathbb{N}^∗\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is completely multiplicative and such that :
$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}^*\,,\, f(n^2+1)-f(n^2)=1\,,$$
then
$$ \forall p\in\mathcal{P},\ (p\equiv 1\;[4] \Rightarrow f(p)=p)  \;\text{and}\;  (p\equiv 3\;[4] \Rightarrow f(p)=\pm p)\,.$$
I came across **[this paper](http://ac.inf.elte.hu/Vol_046_2017/373_46.pdf)** (see Theorem 2 (b2) p. 374), but I'm not really convinced by the end of the proof (see bottom of page 377). What do you think?

There are several things I don't understand:

- Isn't the second case rather $N=Q$
  with $Q≡3\;[4]$
  (not $N=Q^2$
  )?
- It seems to me that all the prime factors $\pi$ of $\frac{Q^2+1}{2}$
  are such that $π≡1\;[4]$, right?
- If we correct the induction hypothesis by "...if $p<N$, $q^2<N$
  ...", a new problem arises : why would we have $f(n^2)=n^2$ ? How can we be sure that a prime factor $\pi$ of $n$ such that $\pi\equiv3\;[4]$ verifies $\pi^2<N$ ?

**(Edit)** I've opened **[another thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4726238/prime-factors-of-k2x21)** on this subject.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. There are several things I don't understand:

- Isn't the second case rather $N=Q$ with $Q\equiv3\;[4]$ (not $N=Q^2$)?

- It seems to me that all the $\pi$ prime factors of $\frac{Q^2+1}{2}$ are such that $\pi\equiv1\;[4]$, right?

I'm sorry, I seem to have missed something simple!

Comment: $N=Q^2$ is fine. What needs a correction is the (strong) induction hypothesis. It should be "...if $p<N,q^2<N$ ...".

Comment: I agree with you on the second point, but I find it can be easily repaired.

Comment: Yes, I agree. $\pi\equiv1\bmod4$ (or $\pi=2$). Then use the (corrected) induction hypothesis.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: In fact, now there's something I don't understand. In the first case, why would we have $f(n^2)=n^2$? How can we be sure that a prime factor $\pi$ of $n$ such that $\pi\equiv3\;[4]$ verifies $\pi^2<N$ ?

Comment: Ok, I'll ask the authors. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Please when you have an answer, edit it here. [It is welcome](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Ok, no problem.

Comment: OPEN EYES: $f(x)=\lfloor x^2+1\rfloor -\lfloor x^2\rfloor$ fits also.

Comment: My eyes are wide open, but in my opinion you should read the initial post more carefully.

Answer (score -3):

Let's consider the case where n=1n=1:
We have f(12+1)−f(12)=f(2)−f(1)=1f(12+1)−f(12)=f(2)−f(1)=1.

Next, consider the case where n=2n=2:
We have f(22+1)−f(22)=f(5)−f(4)=1f(22+1)−f(22)=f(5)−f(4)=1.

From these two cases, we can observe that the difference between the values of ff for consecutive perfect squares is always 1.

In other words, for any positive integer mm, we have f((m+1)2)−f(m2)=1f((m+1)2)−f(m2)=1.

We can express this relationship recursively as follows:
f((m+1)2)=f(m2)+1f((m+1)2)=f(m2)+1.

We can start with an initial condition f(1)=cf(1)=c, where cc is a constant.

Using the recursive relationship, we can compute the values of ff for consecutive perfect squares:
f(2)=f(12)+1=c+1f(32)=f(22)+1=(c+1)+1=c+2f(42)=f(32)+1=(c+2)+1=c+3f(52)=f(42)+1=(c+3)+1=c+4
f(2)f(32)f(42)f(52)​=f(12)+1=c+1=f(22)+1=(c+1)+1=c+2=f(32)+1=(c+2)+1=c+3=f(42)+1=(c+3)+1=c+4​

We can observe that the values of ff for consecutive perfect squares form an arithmetic sequence with the common difference of 1 and the initial term cc.

Therefore, the solution to the given functional equation is f(n)=n+c−1f(n)=n+c−1, where cc is any constant.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Already this is unclear: "Let's consider the case where n=1n=1"