# Prime factors of $k^2x^2+1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, functional-equations

Is there any hope of proving the following conjecture?

> For any integer $x\geq1007$, there exists an integer $k$ such that
> $1\leq k<x$ and such that all the prime factors $p$ of $k^2x^2+1$ satisfy
> $p<x$.

I was able to verify this by computer for $x\leq10^6$.

This result would make it possible to solve the functional equation $f(n^2+1)-f(n^2)=1$ mentioned in **[this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4725035/functional-equation-fn21-fn2-1)**.

Comment: Usually , such conjectures are out of reach. My guess is however that it is true. A number smaller than $x^4$ has a good chance to split into prime factors smaller than $x$. Considering your search limit, I think we can always find such a $k$.

Comment: That the number is of the form $z^2+1$ restricts its prime factors , but still the chance is high enough (at least I think , this is the case) to split into small enough primes.